# Conditional query results

Tags: sql, oracle

Here there is a simplification of the problem.
I have the following table:

```
Student_table
    +-----------+--------------------+---------------------+
    |  Student  |   Graduation_date  |  First_working_date |
    +-----------+--------------------+---------------------+
    |  John     |   12/10/2013       |  15/03/2015         |
    |  Alan     |   22/05/2014       |  12/04/2014         |
    |  Lucy     |   14/03/2014       |  14/03/2014         |
    +-----------+--------------------+---------------------+
```

I would like to write a query that checks if the `Graduation_date is <= First_working_date` and, if so, return a `True` value in an *ad hoc* created column.

Something like this:

```
SELECT Student, IF(Graduation_date <= First_working_date, 'TRUE', 'FALSE') AS Early_Worker
from student_table
```

Having such a result

```
+-----------+--------------------+
|  Student  |   Early_Worker     |
+-----------+--------------------+
|  John     |       FALSE        |
|  Alan     |       TRUE         |
|  Lucy     |       TRUE         |
+-----------+--------------------+
```

I am using Sql on Oracle DB (12g).

Comment: Use a `case` expression.

Comment: SELECT Student, (Graduation_date <= First_working_date) AS Early_Worker FROM student_table.

Comment: @LeonardKlausmann: Oracle has no boolean datatype (in SQL) and thus an expression that returns a boolean in the select list is invalid there (your suggestion **is** valid standard SQL however)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following [CASE-WHEN-ELSE expression](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CASE-Expressions.html#GUID-CA29B333-572B-4E1D-BA64-851FABDBAE96) inside your SQL:

```
SELECT student, 
   ( CASE WHEN Graduation_date <= First_working_date THEN 'TRUE'
          ELSE 'FALSE'
          END ) AS Early_Worker
   FROM student_table;

STUDENT EARLY_WORKER
------- ------------
 John   TRUE
 Alan   FALSE
 Lucy   TRUE
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/66e6aa/1)

Comment: Grazie Barbaros :)

Comment: @Bernheart prego :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is query:

```
SELECT Student,(CASE WHEN Graduation_date <= First_working_date 
THEN
 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END) AS Early_Worker
from student_table
```

Comment: comparing with that of @Barbaros,  I think an END closing keyword is missing in the CASE statement of your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this method:

```
SELECT Student,
CASE WHEN(Graduation_date <= First_working_date) THEN 'True'
ELSE 'False' END AS Early_worker
FROM student_table
```